# gitlab-runner with docker executor cannot find official images like maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Trying to use gitlab-runner with docker executor. I'm using the standard maven `.gitlab-ci.yml` template which identifies the library image `maven:3.3.9-jdk-8`.

For some reason I get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.0 (33af656)
  on 4caf1e03c61d (0cb58cc5)
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: no such image
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: no such image
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: no such image
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): no such image
```

when I `docker exec -it server_gitlab-runner_1 bash` into the container I can reach the internet so I don't think it is a connectivity issue.

Here is my `config.toml` file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "xxx"
  url = "http://gitlab/"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    network_mode = "server_default"
    volumes_from = ["nginx:rw"]
  [runners.cache]
```

The command I use to start the gitlab-runner container is `docker-compose up` and here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:

  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl"
    restart: always

  gitlab:
    image: "gitlab/gitlab-ce"
    volumes:
      - "./gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab"
      - "./gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab"
      - "./gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab"
    restart: always

  gitlab-runner:
    image: "gitlab/gitlab-runner"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner"
    restart: always
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
---
# Build JAVA applications using Apache Maven (http://maven.apache.org)
# For docker image tags see https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/
#
# For general lifecycle information see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
# 
# This template will build and test your projects as well as create the documentation.
# 
# * Caches downloaded dependencies and plugins between invocation.
# * Does only verify merge requests but deploy built artifacts of the
#   master branch.
# * Shows how to use multiple jobs in test stage for verifying functionality
#   with multiple JDKs.
# * Uses site:stage to collect the documentation for multi-module projects.
# * Publishes the documentation for `master` branch.

variables:
  # This will supress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
  # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  # As of Maven 3.3.0 instead of this you may define these options in `.mvn/maven.config` so the same config is used
  # when running from the command line.
  # `installAtEnd` and `deployAtEnd`are only effective with recent version of the corresponding plugins.
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"

# Cache downloaded dependencies and plugins between builds.
cache:
  paths:
    - /root/.m2/repository/

# This will only validate and compile stuff and run e.g. maven-enforcer-plugin. 
# Because some enforcer rules might check dependency convergence and class duplications
# we use `test-compile` here instead of `validate`, so the correct classpath is picked up.
.validate: &validate
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile'

# For merge requests do not `deploy` but only run `verify`.
# See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
.verify: &verify
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify site site:stage'
  except:
    - master

# Validate merge requests using JDK7
validate:jdk7:
  <<: *validate
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-7

# Validate merge requests using JDK8
validate:jdk8:
  <<: *validate
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

# Verify merge requests using JDK7
verify:jdk7:
  <<: *verify
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-7

# Verify merge requests using JDK8
verify:jdk8:
  <<: *verify
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8


# For `master` branch run `mvn deploy` automatically.
# Here you need to decide whether you want to use JDK7 or 8.
# To get this working you need to define a volume while configuring your gitlab-ci-multi-runner.
# Mount your `settings.xml` as `/root/.m2/settings.xml` which holds your secrets.
# See https://maven.apache.org/settings.html
deploy:jdk8:
  # Use stage test here, so the pages job may later pickup the created site.
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy site site:stage'
  only:
    - master
  # Archive up the built documentation site.
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/staging
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8


pages:
  image: busybox:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # Because Maven appends the artifactId automatically to the staging path if you did define a parent pom,
    # you might need to use `mv target/staging/YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID public` instead.
    - mv target/staging public
  dependencies:
    - deploy:jdk8
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but what container do you connect to with docker exec? Are you running gitlab-ci-mutli-runner inside a docker container?

Comment: I think the image is just called gitlab/gitlab-runner now, but yes. (https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner/)

Comment: In that case please add the command you've used to run it.

Comment: I've had similar problems with gitlab runner. I couldn't find the root cause, but for me deleting the build environment image (in your case `maven:3.3.9-jdk-8`) with `docker rmi <image>` helped. 

Sometimes I've also had to delete the service images (you don't seem to use them though).